# Proving that a simple group of order $360$ has 10 Sylow $3$-subgroups and that their pairwise intersection is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I have that $G$ is a simple group of order $360$. By the 2nd, 3rd Sylow theorems we know that there are $n_3 = 1+3k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ Sylow 3-subgroups and that $n_3$ divides $2^3 \cdot 5$, since $360 = 2^3 3^2 5$.

This gives us that $k = 0, k = 1, k = 3, k = 13$. We can immediately rule out $k = 0$ since $G$ is simple. How do I rule out the possibilities $k = 1, k = 13$ and show that their pairwise intersection is the singleton set containing $1$?

edit: I believe $k = 1$ can be ruled out since $1$ is not a prime

Comment: You can rule out $k=1$ because $n_p \ge 5$ for any prime $p$ dividing the order of any finite nonabelian simple group. You really need to know that with problems of this type. You can rule out $k=13$ by using Burnside's Transfer Theorem.

Comment: Where is this result from?

Comment: If the nonabelian simple group $G$ had $n_p$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, then  $G$ is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of the alternating group $A_{n_p}$ (so, in particular $n_p \ge 5$).

Comment: There's a relatively easy way to rule out $k=1$:  If $G$ has exactly $4$ Sylow-$3$ subgroups, then $G$ acts non-trivially by conjugation on the $4$ subgroups, which means the group action defines a homomorphism $f:G \to S_4$.  Then $\ker(f)$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank you, what about the case when k = 13? And why is their pairwise intersection {1}?

Comment: We have not covered Burnside's Transfer Theorem in the course, so unfortunately I cannot use that to rule out k = 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch proof. You need to complete the details yourself.

Suppose two distinct Sylow 3-subgroups $P,Q$ have nontrivial intersection $H$, so $|H|=3$. Then $C_G(H)$ contains $P$ and $Q$, and has at least $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. If it had more than $4$ then its index in $G$ would be too small so it has exactly 4 and $|C_G(H)|=36$ with $C_G(H)/H \cong A_4$. So $C_G(H)$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$ of order $4$ and $N_G(T)$ contains both $C_G(H)$ and a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, so $|N_G(T)| \ge 72$ and its index in $G$ is too small.

So the Sylow $3$-subgroups have trivial intersection. If there were 40 of them, then there are only $39$ elements of $G$ outside of their union.

If $n_5=6$, then $G \cong A_6$, which we know has exactly 10 Sylow $3$-subgroups. So $n_5 \ge 11$, and there are too many elements of order $5$. So we must have $n_3=10$.

Comment: You could simplify the last arguments by using the fact that if $P$ and $Q$ are two *distinct* Sylow $p$-subgroups with $|P \cap Q|$ chosen to be maximal, then $n_p(G) \equiv 1$ mod $|P:P \cap Q|$. So if $P \cap Q=1$ then we get $n_3(G) \equiv 1$ mod $9$, ruling out $n_3(G)=40$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Yes, that's right - please feel free to edit my answer!

Comment: No, let's keep it as it is, plus the comment. That is fine